# W3 Total Cache screws up my website on mobile hosted on Godaddy

Tags: html, css, wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

I am raising this topic after trying to fix the issue myself for about a week. I have read the web and nothing seems to help.
I had installed and configured W3 Total Cache for website load optimization. Things worked well until next morning I found that my website is screwed up. I immediately uninstalled the plugin and deleted folders as per recommendations on Google. It fixed the website on laptop, but responsiveness on mobile is gone. The home page sliders, the font, style everything is screwed up. I checked it on iPhone and Android and the issue is same. I tried uninstalling the plugin and deleting the files as per recommended [here](https://www.devilhax.com/how-to-remove-w3-total-cache-wordpress-plugin-completely/), but all in vain. This is how it looks on mobile:
[image]
**Can you please help me understand a bit about the problem and the way to fix it?**

My website: [www.aashishbarnwal.com](http://aashishbarnwal.com)

Comment: Looks like the mobile version is loading default Bootstrap styles/scripts. Have you tried switching themes and then switching back?

Comment: Thanks! I tried switching theme didn't fix the issue :(

Comment: I would recommend to use `WP_Super_Cache` instead. We are using it within our blog and it's working fine for us. Also, it is more simpler to configure compare to `W3_Total`.

Comment: @BlueSuiter First I need to correct what us screwed. Then only I can go for Super Cache. Right?

Comment: Can you share your admin panel?

Comment: You mean the screenshot?

Comment: yeah that will work fine.

Comment: @BlueSuiter I've already uninstalled W3 Total Cache and removed the residual files. So in the admin panel what details do you need?

Comment: You had premium version or free one?

Comment: I had free one.

Comment: did you deleted all the cached files?? and removed this code `/** Enable W3 Total Cache */
define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache
`

Comment: Yes, I did all.

Comment: did you minified the CSS and JS files, using plugin?? Is the files restored to its normal form again?? Also, if there is any theme switching concept implemented on your website??

Comment: Yes, I did minify CSS and JS files. I don't see any difference in those all files. They look correct to me. My whole website is bult on one theme. There is no theme switching.

Comment: did you kept the configuration files backup of `w3-total-cache` I am trying to recreate the situation on my system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same effect because jetpack module "mobile theme" was installed/activated - As soon as I turned it off, the orignal theme appeared correctly: the "menu" drop-down at the top is very recognisable as the default mobile theme.

Comment: Thanks a ton! You just saved my day. It was jetpack which was optimizing my site for mobile :)